# Interior of sum of discrete set and a set with non-empty interior

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $Z=\{z_1, \cdots, z_m\}$ and $K$ subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\operatorname{int}(K) \not= \emptyset$, then $\operatorname{int}(Z+K)=Z+\operatorname{int}(K)$

I know it is true for just a traslation and it is easy to see the $\supset$-inclusion, but I'm having troubles proving the other one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Here is a counterexample. Let $n=1$, $Z=\{0,1\}$, $K=[0,1]$.
$$\operatorname{int}(Z+K)=\operatorname{int}([0,1]\cup[1,2])=\operatorname{int}([0,2])=(0,2)$$
$$Z+\operatorname{int}(K)=\{0,1\}+(0,1)=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$$
So $\operatorname{int}(Z+K)\not\subseteq Z+\operatorname{int}(K)$, since $1\in\operatorname{int}(Z+K)$ but $1\notin Z+\operatorname{int}(K)$.

Comment: Oh, it is true! I made the mistake of proving in two different ways the same inclusion as in the previous answer. What I was looking for is to prove that if $K$ is convex and compact, then $\operatorname{vol}(Z+K)=\operatorname{vol}(Z+\operatorname{int}(K))$ which I believe it is true and was direct if the question I was asking was true. Do you have any idea on how to prove this fact?